# htaccess adding query string to 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Can sombody help me out with this, im trying to re direct a page using htaccess file but it keeps adding `?c=oldpage` on to the end of the new url, example:

```
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/newpage.html?c=oldpage
```

i have tried some of the solutions posted here but no luck, here is my *`.htaccess`* file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm    
Options +FollowSymLinks    
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PHPSESSID=.*$    
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.co.uk/$1? [R=301,L]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.co.uk$ [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\ HTTP/    
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]    
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^product/(.*).html$ product.php?p=$1 [L]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ category.php?c=$1 [L,NC]        

Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.mydomain.co.uk/newpage.html    

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is mod_alias (the `Redirect` directive) and mod_rewrite not playing nicely with each other. Because both modules apply their directives on the same URI in the URL-file mapping pipeline, they don't know to ignore each other since neither directive knows what the other module is doing. Since you're targets overlap, both modules are applying their directives on the same URI and you get a mish-mashed result.

You need to stick with mod_rewrite in this case and move the redirect above the internal rewrites:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm    
Options +FollowSymLinks    
RewriteEngine on    

# redirects 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PHPSESSID=.*$    
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.co.uk/$1? [R=301,L]    

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.co.uk$ [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]    

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\ HTTP/    
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]    

RewriteRule ^oldpage.html$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/newpage.html [R=301,L]

# internal rewrites
RewriteRule ^product/(.*).html$ product.php?p=$1 [L]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ category.php?c=$1 [L,NC]        

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.abc\.net$
RewriteRule ^example\.html$ "http\:\/\/abc\.net\/example\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteOptions inherit
```

to a folder, or:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.abc\.net$
RewriteRule ^example\.html$ "http\:\/\/abc\.net\/example\.html$" [R=301,L]
RewriteOptions inherit
```

Don't know much about it, but it's what i use, hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply, im not having any luck with this - i bit out of my depth